# How to create a Jquery animation in asp mvc based in another

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2005

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005. I am using Entity Framework with a code-first approach.

I want to make an jquery effect on a link.

I have already this effect in a button and I want to repeat it on another one using also Ajax.

I try it to follow that but I didn't get any result.

I put a video in the bottom of the question describing the animation.

I creat a new Controller named AnouarController :

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{
     [HandleError]
    public class AnouarController : Controller
    {   
    //
    // GET: /Anouar/

     public ActionResult Gestion()
     {
         return View();
     }
   }
}
```

and this is The view Gestion which I would like to show when I click on the button :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>


<asp:Content ID="loginTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Gestion
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="loginContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Gérer</h2>
    </asp:Content>
```

This is a class GestionHelper which I created following the example of the other button :

```
namespace Helpers
{
    public static class GestionHelper
    {
        public static string GestionLinkHelper(this HtmlHelper helper){
            string currentControllerName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            string currentActionName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append("<div id=\"gestionlink\">");

            sb.Append(helper.ActionLink("aaaaa", "Gestion", "Anouar"));
            sb.Append("</div>");
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

and finally,,,this is what I add in the View of the link (which allow the action):

```
<%= Html.GestionLinkHelper() %>
```

This is a video describing the Jquery animation :
[video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtVhQtIHUD4&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Did you check your browser console for any javascript errors. Also post here if you were able to debug and reach the controller during the call.

Comment: no error,,,sorry i forgot to say that when i click on the link,,,the view 'Gestion' appear simply. it s mean without Jquery animation